# Python 3.3 can't import Crypt

Tags: python, python-3.3

When I type in import Crypt on the command line it says:

```
>>>import crypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\crypt.py", line 3, in <module>
    import _crypt
ImportError: No module named '_crypt'
```

Comment: This probably means that Python was built without crypt support. I *guess* that crypt development files were missing. (name of the package varies depending on the OS).

Comment: Ya that's what I figured because it has the crypt.py file there and it shows up under my Modules... If there isn't a solution in a while I think I'm just going to go down to Python 2.

Comment: As casevh notes, the `crypt` module is documented as Unix only.  You won't find it in Python 2, either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`crypt` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt) is an interface to the Unix [`crypt` library](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) which is used for encrypting Unix passwords. It is documented as not being available on Windows. It is not a general purpose cryptography library.

Answer (score 4):

If all you're looking for is an implementation of `crypt(3)`, I've knocked up a pure-Python implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/Cairnarvon/5075687), ported from [this public domain C implementation](http://michael.dipperstein.com/crypt/index.html). It's pretty damn slow (about 2800 times slower than Python's built-in `crypt` on my machine, which is already about half the speed of OpenSSL's `DES_crypt`), but if you're just calculating the occasional hash, that shouldn't really be a problem.

Are you writing an imageboard, by any chance?

Comment: No I was writing a program to connect to my MySQL on my Website and I really needed transferred data to be secured on the computer (as a backup stored on the computer) because multiple have access to the MySQL server and my computer and some data shouldn't be shown.

Comment: You might try collaborating/freshening up this one:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fcrypt/