# python crypt equivalent for windows

Tags: python, encryption, hash, crypt

I am trying to find an equivalent function to [UnixCrypt](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/UnixCrypt.html) in Python for Windows.  What I have found so far is that python does provide a [crypt function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/crypt.html), but it is only for Unix os.  For Windows os, there are [Cairnarvon's crypt.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181739/python-3-3-cant-import-crypt), and [passlib's des_crypt](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.des_crypt.html).  So just as an example, to hash the password, you just have to pass the password and a salt (2-character string) to the functions:

```
from passlib import hash
import crypt as cryptC
pwd = "password"
salt = "JQ"
#Cairnarvon's crypt.py
print(cryptC.crypt(pwd,salt))
# passlib's des crypt
print(hash.des_crypt.encrypt(pwd,salt=salt))
```

Both functions above output the same hash:

```
JQMuyS6H.AGMo
```

However this does not prove that they are giving out the same hash as UnixCrypt or Python's crypt.  To confirm this, I will need a unix os, but I don't.  Can someone kind enough to provide me the hash from UnixCrypt using the password and salt in the above example? Thanks.

Comment: `>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt("password", "JQ")
'JQMuyS6H.AGMo'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'linux'`

Comment: Came back to this post 6 year later only to find I upvoted your reply only, but have not yet thanked you. so Thank you for your time for posting the above! Will accept the answer if you post it as answer. :D

Comment: Yikes, this is a blast from the past! I've posted an answer as requested, although I don't expect this to be useful for many other people.

Comment: Indeed this isn't the kind of question that the site is for IMO. Anyway, about the question: when you do import crypt as cryptC; cryptC.crypt(...) you are just using crypt.crypt, just like I would in Linux. Or am I missing something? By the way, crypt.crypt will use a stronger algorithm if you omit the salt (and use the complete output of crypt as the salt when checking a password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

```py
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 17 2020, 18:15:42) 
[GCC 10.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt("password", "JQ")
'JQMuyS6H.AGMo'
```

```sh
$ uname -ampo
Linux matthew-laptop 5.7.6-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 25 Jun 2020 00:14:47 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also, if you have a choice of algorithm, I would recommend a newer and slower algorithm such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: Cool. Will need to check out those algorithms. After all this time still am a cryptography noob!